# Will Orientdb get a slow query log?

Tags: orientdb

Are there plans to implement a slow query log in ODB?

The explain command is nice, but before I can find out issues with queries with the explain command, I need to know which queries need optimizing.

Or is there some other way of getting slow queries out of a running ODB system?

Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [profiler](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Studio-Query-Profiler.html). It is available only with enterprise edition.